# Django database design

Tags: python, django, database

I am writing an online payroll system and I am having problems to design my database.
A client can contract our program. His information is stored in model "Client". A client can have one or more companies (model "Companies"). Each company has staff (model "Staff") and a staff has a set of other models for adress, tax, social security etc.
If a staff has changes in his data (for example a new name after a wedding, or changes in the tax data) a new record with the date of the change will be registered (field "xxx_valid" in models). The old record has to be kept in database for historical reasons.

Here are my models:

```
class Client (models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField (...)
    ....

class Company (models.Model):
    clientID = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    company_name = models.CharField (...)
    ....

class Staff (models.Model):
    clientID = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    companyID = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    staff_nr = models.IntegerField (....)
    staff_valid = models.DateField (....)
    staff_name = models.CharField (...)
    ....

class StaffTax (model.Model):
    clientID = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    companyID = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    staffID = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    tax_valid = models.DateField (....)
    tax_nr = models.CharField (...)
    ....

class StaffSocSec (model.Model):
    clientID = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    companyID = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    staffID = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    sosec_valid = models.DateField (....)
    sosec_nr = models.CharField (....)
    ....
```

Everything works fine if a staff has no history.
Now lets say, a staff gets a new period in model Staff (field staff_valie) because his address has changed. This new record will get a new id (pk)
If the payroll calculacion is started, the latest record of Staff will be used.
Querysets to StaffTayx etc are made using the StaffID.
But the tax information are related with the first (old) record in model Staff and the queryset woun't find any records.

Of course I could ignore ID, define staffID in the models StaffTax (and others) as a normal Charfield and make my queryset using this normal Charfield instead of using the primery key id.
But I would loose a lot of funcionality like automatic created options for  in a modelformset.

Nor I can set staffID has primery key, because an other client could have the same StaffID and I get an unique error.

Anybody has a idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to be able to keep a history of changes to your model's data.  There are a few options out there, see [this list on Django packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/).

In terms of editing the history and viewing reports, [django-simple-history](http://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org) could be a good match.  That has [admin integration](http://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#integration-with-django-admin) and the ability to [query the history](http://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#querying-history) easily.

Alternatively

Comment: thanks seddonym, but I am not sure if django-revions will work for me. The user frequently wants to access to the old records, reports can be printed with old data and the user may edit old data to correct errors and recalculate the payroll for old records. 
I read the docs and it seams I always have to restore old data before using them, which make the thing very complicated

Comment: There are a few other packages that might help with that, I've updated my answer accordingly.